# Variable "emergencyIntent" might not have been initialized

Tags: android

I'm new to Android programming. I'm creating a button that is going to open a blank activity page called *emergencyIntent*

```
package com.example.xxx.buttonexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnClick();
}
public void btnClick() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent emergencyIntent = new Intent(this,emergencyIntent.java);
            startActivity(emergencyIntent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I receive an error "Variable "emergencyIntent" might not have been initialized."

I've created the emergencyIntent class, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Intent emergencyIntent = new Intent(this,emergencyIntent.java);
```

should most likely be:

```
Intent emergencyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EmergencyIntent.class);
```

otherwise it looks like you're trying to access the member variable `java` from instance `emergencyIntent`. which has not been initialized yet, because you're only just creating it. Presumably that's not what you want and you're trying to pass the *filename* of your class, which is just not how it works.

Since you're not showing your `EmergencyIntent` class I'm not sure of the exact spelling of it.

Comment: I changed it to the above, but I received a error: "Cannot resolve constructor 'intent(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.lang.Class)'. 

Any idea on how to overcome this? Any solution is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use MainActivity.this instead of this.